# Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name is disappeared from build setting

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project in xcode with different targets. In the built targets I cannot find the *Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name* and icons are not displayed. Anyone know how i could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I had finally to add in the Build Phases > copy Bundle Resources the assets which include the icons. 
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your config Looks like this
[image]